# Implement TypeScript interface with [foo] properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement the nanostore `ReadableAtom` interface which defines two unusual properties:

```
export interface ReadableAtom<Value = any> {
   ...
   readonly [actionId]: number | undefined
   readonly [lastAction]: string | undefined
```

What are these bracketed property declarations and how would I actually implement them to satisfy the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `actionId` and `lastAction` are predefined `unique symbols`.

They must have been defined something like this

```html
declare const actionId: unique symbol;
declare const lastAction: unique symbol;
```

You can implement the interface like this

```html
const a: ReadableAtom = {
   [actionId]: 12,
   [lastAction]: "test"
}
```

Comment: Don't forget OP will have to import those symbols from the library. They may not be aware of that...

Answer (score 0):

The bracketed property declaration in TypeScript signifies computed property names. This implies that the property names are determined dynamically at runtime. As for your second question, if you could reformulate or clarify what you intend to do with the computed properties, we might be able to assist you better.

Comment: ...this answer is incorrect: Typescript interfaces compile away and have no runtime reification, there is no way those *types* could be dynamically computed at runtime. That is only used for symbol keys when writing type declarations, it can be used for the sort of dynamically computed property names when writing *values*.

Comment: @JaredSmith Type information is indeed removed at runtime, but the types [can still have the information](https://tsplay.dev/Wo1D9N) about a certain property key being computed at runtime.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine that's a great catch thanks. Still, I'm struggling to think of a valid use case for that vs `Record<string, string>` etc